# Installed Jetty via Yum (CentOS), but can't find start.jar to run it

Tags: yum, jetty

`<UPDATE>`/etc/init.d/ doesn't appear to contain any relevant entry (retrieved via `ls -A`):

```
abrtd         certmonger  firstboot  irqbalance     mysqld          nscd     portreserve  rpcidmapd   snmpd      vmware-tools
acpid         cgconfig    functions  kdump          netconsole      nslcd    postfix      rpcsvcgssd  snmptrapd  vncserver
atd           cgred       haldaemon  killall        netfs           ntpd     psacct       rsyslog     sshd       webmin
auditd        cpuspeed    halt       lvm2-monitor   network         ntpdate  rdisc        sandbox     sssd       wpa_supplicant
autofs        crond       httpd      mdmonitor      NetworkManager  oddjobd  restorecond  saslauthd   sysstat    ypbind
avahi-daemon  cups        ip6tables  messagebus     nfs             openct   rpcbind      single      tomcat6
bluetooth     dnsmasq     iptables   microcode_ctl  nfslock         pcscd    rpcgssd      smartd      udev-post
```

The good news is that installation without using Yum is as simple as unpacking the manually-downloaded archive, which contains the directory structure that all the "how-to" guides expect. However, this still doesn't explain why Yum provides a non-functional installation. Since there are probably quite a few people who automatically turn to Yum to get their packages, a more satisfactory answer would be nice, for their sake.`</UPDATE>`

I'm pretty new to CentOS (and Linux in general) and am trying out a few different servlet containers. I've already got Tomcat installed and capable of running a few example servlets, so I know the basic infrastructure works. I then installed Jetty via Yum (`yum install jetty-eclipse`), which completed successfully. I then found [this guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Running+Jetty-6.1.x) which explains how to start the service, by executing start.jar in the install directory. Not knowing where Yum installed Jetty, I did a `locate start.jar` and got no hits. I then tried `locate jetty` and got the following:

```
/usr/share/jetty-eclipse
/usr/share/doc/jetty-eclipse-6.1.21
/usr/share/doc/jetty-eclipse-6.1.21/NOTICE.txt
/usr/share/doc/jetty-eclipse-6.1.21/VERSION.txt
/usr/share/java/jetty-eclipse
/usr/share/java/jetty-eclipse/jetty-6.1.21.jar
/usr/share/java/jetty-eclipse/jetty-util-6.1.21.jar
/usr/share/java/jetty-eclipse/jetty-util.jar
/usr/share/java/jetty-eclipse/jetty.jar
/usr/share/jetty-eclipse/lib
/usr/share/jetty-eclipse/lib/jetty-6.1.21.jar
/usr/share/jetty-eclipse/lib/jetty-util-6.1.21.jar
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/j/5b1dd996cd90f600ab0ed756a9966a3787871107-jetty-eclipse-6.1.21-1.el6-noarch/releasever
```

Even assuming that /usr/share/jetty-eclipse/ is the installation directory, all the guides I've seen assume that there is a start.jar file plainly visible somewhere, which is not true in my case. It obviously doesn't make sense for Yum to install a service that cannot run, so what am I missing?

Comment: Check to see if there is already an init script in `/etc/init.d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bad package. Not only is start.jar missing but also some of the other jetty jars like jetty-jsp, jetty-servlet and even basic documentation. Compare it with the rpm for Fedora; amazing difference.

To save yourself aggravation in future:

- to list a package's files, run: `rpm -ql jetty-eclipse`
- `locate` queries a database that is periodically refreshed by a cron job running `updatedb`. You could force the issue by issuing the command yourself.